# Adding map markers with php, javascript and json

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, google-maps-markers

Trying to add markers from mysql by retrieving them using php and then json_encode()to then use the results in javascript. Currently I the map is displaying for me, but the markers are not!

MarkersController.php - fetching information from database.

```
$list = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $list[] = array(
        array('lat' => $lat), 
        array('lng' => $lng));
}
echo json_encode($list);
```

Landing.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
                    <script type = "text/javascript"
                            src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
                            key=AIzaSyB76xBqfQdgOLV77VK3JZ09vWwk8brkMFs">
                    </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                var map = null;
                                function addMarker(lat, lng) {
                                var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                        position: myLatLng,
                                                map: map
                                        });
                                }


                        function initialize() {
                        var mapOptions = {
                        center: {lat: 54.872128, lng: - 6.284874},
                                zoom: 13
                        };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                        mapOptions);

        $.getJSON('MarkersController.php', function(data){
                                $.each(data, function(lat, lng){
                                addMarker('lat', 'lng');
                                });
                                })
                            }
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

                    </script>
```

Trying to use the array from MarkersController.php to implement the addMarker() function.

Comment: How are they "not working"? Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: if you show the output you are receiving from $.getJSON to your MarkersController.php it would help us to know where the problem is

Comment: @RowlandShaw There are no errors in my console, and the markers are not showing on the map!

Answer (score 0):

Try `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before your echo or the result you are getting from server will be plain text.